# Directshow Hardware encoding for webcam Logitech C930e

Tags: video, webcam, directshow, h.264, video-capture

i'm trying capture video with the webcam logitech c930e use hardware encoded stream (Windows 8.1 x64). Try many way but still no success (ffmpeg only show mjpeg, directshow cannot connect pin to mp4mux, only connect to MS DTV-DVD Video Decoder).

Is there anyway to capture video with this webcam use hardware encoded ?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Since this is not a programming question please ask on [**SuperUser.com**](http://superuser.com/). Click "join this community" on that page to use your current account. Also show what commands you tried in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To consume Logitech C930e's H.264 video you might need an adapter filter which coverts camera's video to standard H.264 media type.

Or, [this fork of GDCL mp4mux project](https://github.com/roman380/gdcl.co.uk-mpeg4), for example, accepts the camera's H.264 directly:

[image]

You can also consume and record this H.264 video naturally using Media Foundation API. Standard Windows Store Camera application is capable of doing exactly this (at least in Windows 10 before Anniversary update, or otherwise with Frame Server disabled or possibly with most recent patches).

Comment: what i need is a solution so i can encode video (use HW) for short time(10~20 sec) and save to file. I already try use Windows Camera app, seem it encode use MJPEG stream when encode CPU is around 5~8%, and the result file is ~80MB/30sec, i use handbrake encode with highprofile it turn to 15mb. That's mean the video isn't encode properly right (i mean uncompressed) ?

Comment: If your question is a programming question, then you can use Media Foundation API (well, DirectShow as well). Capture of hardware H.264 video from this camera is possible. Popular apps may be unable to do that though, but in this case if you are interested to fir them then it's not a StackOverflow question.

Comment: i prefer use DirectShow, however any idea how to get the hardware H.264 video from this camera ? i use mp4mux and it not accept the pin

Comment: See link above for mp4mux which accepts camera's H.264.

Comment: thanks man! everything working now! one last question : can i set the size of the video ? seem it set to 640x480 here

Comment: As usual programmatically (IAMStreamConfig::SetFormat or IFilterGraph2::ConnectDirect with media type), or with media type choices in GraphStudioNext interactively (Ctrl+Shit+M)